# Bootstrap Carousel Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a number of issues with bootstrap's carousel:

1. The carousel doesn't render until the first interval elapses. I
   don't even want the carousel to autoplay, so I tried using the
   option interval: false, but that causes the carousel to never
   render.
2. When I click the next or prev button it's putting the
   #carousel in the url, which is highly undesired.

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="contributors-carousel carousel slide">

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="contributor">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="http://redacted/image.gif" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="contributor">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="http://redacted/image.gif" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="contributor">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="http://redacted/image.gif" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

Feel free to try it yourself:

[redacted]

Comment: why is your Carousel id `#myCarousel`? Your current jQuery selector isn't returning what you think. If your going to use your current html markup then your selector will have to be `$('#\\#myCarousel')`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo... in my code it's not actually like that.

Comment: I added the url so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things to fix in your code

- as @Blake said, your id must be `myCarousel` or you must change your selector
- you didn't specify what image will be visible first (class `active` on one of the `item`)
- you did something strange with the `contributors-carousel`

Here is a bootply with your code fixed : http://bootply.com/69067

Comment: What do you mean by "you did something strange with the contributors-carousel"?

Comment: look at my bootply, you didnt use it the way it is supposed to be ;)

Comment: I did. What I can tell is that I was missing the indicators. Otherwise, it looks the same to me. Am I missing something? Regardless, I added the indicators section and the "active" class and I'm getting exactly the same results.

Comment: Actually, adding the "active" link does fix the issue with it taking `interval` seconds to render. Thinking about it, this totally makes sense. The only issue remaining is that clicking on the nav links adds "#myCarousel" at the end of the url in the address bar. This is bad because it makes my page navigate instead of going to the next slide.

Comment: i said that because you put the class `contributors-carousel` on your div having the class `Carousel` and its not the way it's supposed to be. but yes that was not causing your issue, it was just a side note ;)

Comment: Got it.. thanks! Any idea why the nav buttons are changing the url?

Comment: while navigating on the link you provided, the address bar is always `http://twitter-gregg.authorbee.com/stories/2`, what nav links are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Did you click the ellipses? When you do, it will reveal the carousel. When you click on the left or right arrow, it will change the url. Let me know if you can't find it.

Comment: i feel like a dummy but i dont get it, gimme the link ;)

Comment: Hey hey, you've already proven you're not a dummy! I've added a screenshot of where to click on my original post. Let me know if that doesn't clarify things.

Comment: got it :] mmmh, hard to explain this behavior without reducing the code to something easier to read. i might have a lead to help you, check this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NqgCW/ . Copy / paste this code in a page using jquery (because it doesnt affect the address bar directly on the jsfiddle). you'll see that the first link adds a # to the address bar, but the second doesn't, thanks to the `preventDefault`. Try to find what part of your code displays the carousel and you should be able to fix it using this trick ! Hope i'm clear :)

Comment: I figured it out. The issue isn't with Bootstrap and it wasn't anything I was doing wrong. The issue was with angularjs (the magical js framework that I've been forced to use and that I thoroughly hate). Angular doesn't play nice with bootstrap, which is where there's this: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. That's right, an entire build of bootstrap just for angular. Throwing up yet? This post led me to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874718/angularjs-and-bootstrap-javascript. Thank you for your help!